# How to use Spring Boot Autoconfiguration for Spring Kafka's exactly once delivery?

Tags: spring-kafka

How to use Spring Boot Autoconfiguration to enable exactly once delivery in Spring Kafka?

Would just setting `spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix` be enough? Or do I need anything else as well?

Also, do I also need to enable idempotence as suggested by a few blogs? Or would enabling transactions anyways make sure that my producer is idempotent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assumption is correct. As long as you use auto-configured `KafkaTemplate` in a listener thread, you got a proper Kafka transaction.

No, you don't need to configure idempotency in case of transactions.

See more info in respective Kafka docs: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_transactional.id